# SQL Inner join how to show a combination only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

At the moment my code is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Research a 
INNER JOIN Research b 
    ON a.DateTime = b.DateTime AND a.Unit = b.Unit 
INNER JOIN Research c 
    ON c.DateTime = b.DateTime AND c.Unit = b.Unit 
WHERE
  a.MessageId != b.MessageId AND a.MessageId != c.MessageId AND b.MessageId != c.MessageId
```

Then I get the folowing output

> MessageId | MessageId | MessageId 
> 9 7 8 
> 8 7 9 
> 7 9 8 
> 7 8 9 
> 9 8 7 
> 8 9 7

How can I make a query that only shows one combination?

Comment: Please show the results you are starting with.  Show the results you want. You could also set up a db/SQL fiddle.

Comment: The ouctome is correct, only I don't need 6 exactly the same answers in a different order that's the problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want triples but not duplicates due to ordering use `<`/`>` instead of `<>`:

```
SELECT r.*, r2.*, r3.*
FROM Research r JOIN
     Research r2
     ON r2.DateTime = r.DateTime AND
        r2.Unit = r.Unit AND
        r2.MessageId > r.MessageId JOIN
     Research r3
     ON r3.DateTime = r2.DateTime AND
        r3.Unit = r2.Unit AND
        r3.MessageId > r2.MessageId ;
```

This returns the three rows ordered by `MessageId`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Research a 
INNER JOIN Research b ON a.DateTime = b.DateTime AND a.Unit = b.Unit AND a.MessageId < b.MessageId 
INNER JOIN Research c ON c.DateTime = b.DateTime AND c.Unit = b.Unit AND b.MessageId < c.MessageId
```

You don't need the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean with showing only one combination but if you want to set a limit for the amount of records to return use TOP

**Example**

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table;
```

In your case you want only one record so use TOP 1

Answer (score -1):

Simply add "LIMIT 1" to the end of your query, and you should have only 1 result.

Limit is used exactly for that, to limit the number of rows returned.
More info can be found [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

Comment: . . Besides the point that `LIMIT` is probably not the right solution here, SQL Server doesn't support `LIMIT`.  I would suggest that you just delete the answer.